# Add Adsense to a website but the server responds with error 510

Tags: html, google, ads, adsense

I'm trying to add Ads to my website.
The website is made with Wordpress.

I'm going to `Options < Adsense < Ad Manager`

Then I click manage Ads.
After that, google starts to analyze my page.
After that it shows me places where I can add an ad.
If I add one an click save, I get the following error:

[image]

In English this means:

> The configuration could not be saved . Your server returned to the
>   request the error code 510

The google support couldn't help me :(

Answer (score 0):

You get an Error 510 when you've exceeded allowed server resources. In your case is most likely to be connection limits. Instances of this have been seen on Apache (CentOS) Server running Plesk.

> Not Extended A mandatory extension policy in the request is not
>   accepted by the server for this resource.

Check to see if you have bandwidth or connection limits you can adjust. If on a shared server contact the server support.

There may be something in your error_log but there's a good chance it will be at server level, not account level.

More info can be found here https://ma.ttias.be/plesk-throws-a-mandatory-extension-policy-in-the-request-is-not-accepted-by-the-server-for-this-resource/